# Find $c \in (a,b)$ such that $\int_{a}^{c}f(t)dt=f(c)$ if $f$ is continuous and $\int_{a}^{b}f(t)dt=0$

Tags: functions, continuity

Given a continuous function $f(x)$ such that $\int_{a}^{b}f(t)dt=0$ , prove that there exists $c\in (a,b)$ such that $\int_{a}^{c}f(t)dt=f(c)$.

I designated $F(x)=\int_{a}^{x}f(t)dt$  and the question becomes to show that $\exists c$, s.t $F(c)-F'(c)=0$ .

If we set $G(x)=F(x)-F'(x)$, by the continuity of $G(x)$ and by the fact that $G(a)=-f(a)$ , $G(b)=-f(b)$, if the signs of $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ are opposite than there exists such $c$ as required.

But How can I show that such $c$ also exist if the signs of $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ are not opposite? Alternatively, can we show that the signs must be opposite?

Comment: At some point the signs will have to switch but $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ still could have the same sign

Comment: Hint : Put $H(x)=F(x)\exp(-x)$. You have $H(a)=H(b)=0$. Compute the derivative of $H$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is no such $c$ then (by continuity) either $\int_a^{x} f(t)dt-f(x) >0$ for all $x$ or $\int_a^{x} f(t)dt-f(x) <0$ for all $x$. Suppose $\int_a^{x} f(t)dt-f(x) >0$ for all $x$. Then $(e^{-x}F(x))'=e^{-x} (f(x)-F(x)) <0$ for all $x$. Hence $e^{-x}F(x)$ is a decreasing function. In particular $e^{-a}F(a)>e^{-b}F(b)$ which means $0 >0$, a contradiction. Similarly we get a contradiction when $\int_a^{x} f(t)dt-f(x) <0$ for all $x$.